# My redis initialization function possibly causing memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, redis, closures

```
const redis = require('redis');

module.exports = function redisClientConfig(app) {
  const redisClient = redis.createClient(app.get('redis-config'));

  redisClient.on('connect', () => {
    app.redisClient = redisClient;
  });
};
```

This function is only being called once but it causes memory leak.

My hunch is that `app.redisClient` closes into `redisClient` everytime the event `connect` happens. This part confuses me. Can someone explain it to me further?

Answer (score 0):

`createClient` function from the `redis` module returns the clients synchronously, therefore, you don't need to wait for the `connect` event. You can directly set the returned client from the `createClient` function on your `app` object. If the memory leak is in fact caused by this function, this should solve it.